# Prove that $p_1\cdots p_k - 1$ and $p_1\cdots p_l - 1$ are coprime and that $p_1\cdots p_k + 1$ and $p_1\cdots p_l+1$ are coprime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Let $p_n$ denote the nth prime and suppose $l\neq k$. Prove or disprove that $p_1\cdots p_k - 1$ and $p_1\cdots p_l - 1$ are coprime. Prove or disprove that $p_1\cdots p_k + 1$ and $p_1\cdots p_l+1$ are coprime.

For the first proof, I'm thinking of showing that $p_1\cdots p_k - 1$ divides some number less than $p_1\cdots p_l - 1$ that is clearly coprime to $p_1\cdots p_l-1$, but I can't find this number. The motivation being that one can show that for $k\neq l, F_k | (F_l - 2)$, where $F_k$ is the kth Fermat number.

Edit: the second one is false.

Just trying a few values, we get the following table, from which I can't seem to find any useful patterns:

| k | $p_1\cdots p_k - 1$ | $p_1\cdots p_k + 1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 3 | 29 | 31 |
| 4 | 209 | 211 |
| 5 | 2309 | 2311 |
| 6 | 30029 | 30031 |

Perhaps something like the law of quadratic reciprocity or the Legendre/Jacobi symbol could be useful? For instance, one can use the law of quadratic reciprocity to show that every divisor of the nth Fermat number is of the form $k2^{n+2} + 1$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: You might want to use that if a prime divides two integers then it divides their difference.

Comment: If [the factorizations at the bottom of this OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A038507/a038507.txt) or those [here](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/matha1/matha103.htm) are correct, this isn't true: both 149#-1 and 193#-1 are divisible by 673.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are false. The second has already been commented on, so here are some counter-examples for the first.

Let $F_k=p_1\cdots p_k-1$.

The first counter-example is
$F_{19}=7858321551080267055879089$,
$F_{22}=3217644767340672907899084554129$,
with $\gcd(F_{19},F_{22})=163$.

Following that, for $F_n$ with $n$ up to 1000:
$\gcd(F_{35},F_{44})=673$,
$\gcd(F_{144},F_{405})=54493$,
$\gcd(F_{134},F_{412})=6637$,
$\gcd(F_{12},F_{432})=38669$,
$\gcd(F_{161},F_{457})=4219$,
$\gcd(F_{116},F_{466})=4397$,
$\gcd(F_{270},F_{480})=13577$,
$\gcd(F_{232},F_{499})=7691$,
$\gcd(F_{573},F_{678})=62299$,
$\gcd(F_{257},F_{701})=12893$,
$\gcd(F_{353},F_{702})=6197$,
$\gcd(F_{486},F_{705})=6871$,
$\gcd(F_{36},F_{729})=24083$.

Similarly, for $G_k=p_1\cdots p_k+1$:
$\gcd(G_{7},G_{17})=277$,
$\gcd(G_{33},G_{102})=1657$,
$\gcd(G_{47},G_{131})=1051$,
$\gcd(G_{37},G_{184})=1381$,
$\gcd(G_{98},G_{185})=3373$,
$\gcd(G_{37},G_{205})=1867$,
$\gcd(G_{206},G_{263})=3041$,
$\gcd(G_{8},G_{298})=27953$,
$\gcd(G_{144},G_{362})=32983$,
$\gcd(G_{53},G_{397})=3499$,
$\gcd(G_{206},G_{409})=3041$,
$\gcd(G_{263},G_{409})=3041$,
$\gcd(G_{293},G_{410})=33547$,
$\gcd(G_{393},G_{430})=3001$,
$\gcd(G_{216},G_{536})=5147$,
$\gcd(G_{470},G_{556})=4637$,
$\gcd(G_{215},G_{585})=4877$,
$\gcd(G_{190},G_{634})=10987$,
$\gcd(G_{285},G_{636})=3764351$,
$\gcd(G_{85},G_{736})=6673$,
$\gcd(G_{521},G_{747})=7547$,
$\gcd(G_{776},G_{896})=24917$,
$\gcd(G_{550},G_{901})=14797$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second the answ is negative.

https://oeis.org/A006862

Comment: Is there some way to determine whether the answer for the second one is negative without using a computer?

Comment: I don't think but I'm not sure.